# Facebook API in Single Page App handling of tokens and security

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, single-page-application, access-token

Goal: A single page application that uses Facebook authentication to login, but does nothing with Facebook after that.

Tech: Facebook Javascript SDK, AngularJS, angular-ui, .Net Web Api

I'm creating a Single Page Application (SPA) in Javascript using AngularJS. I'm using the Facebook SDK which is working to authenticate the user; it returns me a facebook user id, an access token, token expiry time, a signed request, and some other stuff, all on the client side. I then pass this information to my service, mostly because I feel I should. After this I don't really care about Facebook. But I want to make calls to the server to load the user's data.

I could just make all requests using the facebook user id, but there would be no security because any client could just call that endpoint and pass any user id until they found a valid one.

I could use the access token on each request as well, but I still think this is a security failure; when the user first logs in and I pass it to the server, well that endpoint could also be called by any client... "LoginServer('myfakeaccesstoken', $knownUserId)

I get the feeling that I should validate the token on the server side back with facebook, and then I can safely rely on teh token on future API calls, but I'm wondering if there are any other approaches?

The Facebook documentation seems to focus too much on me wanting to make follow up calls to their graph API when I really don't care after my user is authenticated.

Comment: You should verify the user’s identity, as outlined in the FB documentation. I you don’t want to make any API calls after that, then I’d suggest you use your own session afterwards.

Comment: Yes I can track my user's session, but I can't confirm that the original call to the restful service is from my app's JS as opposed to a malicious user trying to generate a new session with someone else's user id. It's kind of the point of the whole question above to be honest.

Comment: When you send the access token on the initial call and use that to make an API request, that is not fake-able.